# ¿Como Consultar a la base de datos en angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs

¡Estoy trabajando con angularJS, proyecto creado con YEOMAN-Generator!

y necesito hacer una consulta a una base de datos.

Pensé que podía integrar `php` con una consulta simple pero aún así no me deja. ¿Cómo lo hice? bien, aquí les dejo el código:

Dentro de la carpeta **app** he creado una carpeta llamada php y en ella cree un archivo que llamé **conection** que contiene la conexión :

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "saltala");

?>
```

y otro archivo llamado **consulta.php**:

```
     <?php

require_once 'conection.php';

$query = "SELECT rut, numero, servicio_id FROM Tickets";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$arr = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$arr[] = $row;}

}

echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);

?>
```

y en la carpeta **controller** donde se ubican los controladores del proyecto, cree el siguiente código:

```
    //     comienza la  conexion

    getInfo();
function getInfo(){

$http.post('php/consulta.php').success(function(data){

$scope.details = data;

    console.log(data);
})};


//  finaliza la conexion
```

En primera instancia ejecute con `gulp serve` y no me reconoció para nada el `php`, así que cambie de ubicación la carpeta del proyecto a **htdocs** dentro de **xampp** y lo ejecute y me arrojo los datos que necesitaba!.

saludos.

Comment: en mysql_query necesitas enviar tanto el query como el objeto que hace referencia a la conexion entiendase "linker" osea en tu caso la variable $con mysql_query($query,$con) manuerumx tiene razon, deberías obtar por usar mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

No uses las funciones mysql, estás ya están depreciadas. Necesitas usar mysqli

http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php

Y el problema no radica en AngularJS (Angular 1), el problema esta en el código PHP, no se que versión de PHP usas, pero es factible que el problema se deba a la libreria que estas usando. Lo que es un hecho, es que no se esta estableciendo la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: cambie el código por mysqli

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un typo en la linea  `echo json_encode($dato);` debe ser `echo json_encode($data);`, reaclaro: $data no $dato, ahora tambien debes ocultar los warnings [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)  `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);` al inicio del scope de php, para proximas preguntas porfavor agrega las versiones exactas, ya que esas librerias estaria deprecadas en las nuevas versiones.

Comment: como veo la versión? estoy editando la pregunta. gracias.

Comment: Describe tu ambiente de trabajo completo, la version de php es `phpinfo();` , ademas en la imagen subrayaste el codigo de error, si miras 2 lineas abajo, ves donde dice ALLOW: Solo tienes permitido GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, mas NO POST. Debes configurar tu codigo para que permita POST o mas sencillo, tu llamado ajax(desde el ladoi de node.js) para que se envie como GET y no como POST